# Get cumulative sum using field names set earlier in the query

Tags: jinja2, dbt

I have a for loop embedded in my query that takes some categorical variables, renames it with a "total" in front of it (also replaces spaces with underscores), and then sums a different field, AMOUNT, tied to the variable.

```
{% set columns = ("transfer out", "transfer in", "fee" %}
  {% for column in columns %}
    , round(
      sum(case when table.variable = '{{ column }}'  then table.amount else 0 end)
      , 2) as total_{{ column|replace(" ", "_")|replace("-", "_") }}s
  {% endfor %}
```

Say this creates:

| column | amount |
| --- | --- |
| total_transfer_outs | -90 |
| total_transfer_ins | 100 |
| total_fees | -10 |

In the same query, I want to be able to get the sum of the 3 new columns that were created.
sum(total_transfer_outs    + total_transfer_ins + total_fees ) = (-90 +100 -10) = 0. Note: this list could expand to >3 variables in the future, so I assume I need to use some sort of loop and cumulative sum to make this scalable.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out you can just loop over it using a plus sign and starting from zero. I was trying to solve this using cumulative sum and/or append functions. This works though...

```
,0
  {% for column in columns %}
     + (total_{{ column|replace(" ", "_")|replace("-", "_") }}s) 
  {% endfor %} 
as sum_of_everything
```